# Property 'tipoInstrumento' does not exist on type 'Instrumento'. Did you mean 'idInstrumento'?

Tags: angular

Update: I was returning Instrumento at the pipe...

I'm trying to do an ngFor on a table, it works when I try to debug, but when I try to publish, I get that error:

Instrumento.component.html

```
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-title">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>Instrumentos</h2>
          <p *ngIf="!instrumentos"><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></p>
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
          <a *ngIf="instrumentos" routerLink="create/0" class="btn bs-tooltip-right"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i> Crear</a>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input class="form-control buscador" placeholder="Buscar instrumento" id="buscador" name="buscador" [(ngModel)]="value" >
          </div>
          </div>
          <table class='table table-hover' aria-labelledby="tableLabel" *ngIf="instrumentos">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nombre instrumento</th>
                <th>Tipo instrumento</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let instrumento of instrumentos|instrumentoPipe:value; let i = index">
                <td>{{ instrumento.nombreInstrumento }}</td>
                <td>{{ instrumento.tipoInstrumento <---- error}}</td>
                <td><a [routerLink]="['edit', instrumento.idInstrumento]" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Editar</a></td>
                <td><a (click)="deleteInstrumento(instrumento.idInstrumento)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a></td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

instrumento.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemePalette } from '@angular/material/core';
import { ProgressSpinnerMode } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { TipoInstrumento } from '../models/tipo-instrumento';
import { InstrumentoService } from '../services/instrumento.service';
import { TipoInstrumentoService } from '../services/tipo-instrumento.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'instrumento',
  templateUrl: './instrumento.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./instrumento.component.css']
})
export class InstrumentoComponent implements OnInit {

  instrumentosSC: any[];
  instrumentos: InstrumentoTipoInstrumento[];
  tipoInstrumento: TipoInstrumento[];

  color: ThemePalette = 'primary';
  mode: ProgressSpinnerMode = 'indeterminate';
  value: string = '';


  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private instrumentoService: InstrumentoService, route: ActivatedRoute, private tipoInstrumentoService: TipoInstrumentoService) {
  }


  getInstrumento() {
    this.instrumentoService.GetInstrumento().subscribe(result => this.getTipoInstrumentos(result), error => this.toastr.error("Hubo un error al cargar los instrumentos" + error, "Error"));

  }

  deleteInstrumento(id: number) {
    this.instrumentoService.DeleteInstrumento(id).subscribe(result => this.toastr.success("Instrumento eliminado exitosamente", "Éxito"), error => this.toastr.error("Hubo un error al eliminar el instrumento " + error, "Error"));

  }

  getTipoInstrumentos(result) {
    this.instrumentosSC = result;
    this.tipoInstrumentoService.GetTipoInstrumento().subscribe(result => this.mapInstrumentos(result), error => this.toastr.error("Hubo un error al cargar Tipo Instrumento" + error, "Error"));
  }

  mapInstrumentos(result) {
    this.tipoInstrumento = result;
    this.instrumentos = this.instrumentosSC.map(instrumento => {
      return {
        idInstrumento: instrumento.idInstrumento,
        nombreInstrumento: instrumento.nombreInstrumento,
        tipoInstrumentoIdTipoInstrumento: instrumento.tipoInstrumentoIdTipoInstrumento,
        tipoInstrumento: this.getTipoInstrumentoById(instrumento.tipoInstrumentoIdTipoInstrumento).nombreTipoInstrumento
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getInstrumento();
  }

  getTipoInstrumentoById(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
    return this.tipoInstrumento.find(tipoInstrumentos => {
      return tipoInstrumentos.idTipoInstrumento === id;
    })
  }


}

interface InstrumentoTipoInstrumento {
  idInstrumento?: number;
  nombreInstrumento: string;
  tipoInstrumentoIdTipoInstrumento: number;
  tipoInstrumento: string;
}
```

As you can see, I do a map to "Instrumentos" to get the "tipoInstrumento", but, or some reason, the "let instrumento of..." recognices instrumento as type "Instrumento", another model I have, but I can't find why is it marking it as "Instrumento" if it should be "InstrumentoTipoInstrumento"

Comment: Can you show us the `instrumentoPipe` pipe? I think this pipe is not returning a `InstrumentoTipoInstrumento`, but some another type.

Comment: Yeah, it was the pipe... Many thanks!